# infinity and nan values

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, printf, infinity

I use gcc-mingw,4.5.2 on Winows 7.
printf of infinity and nan values causes 1.#INF00 and -1.#IND00  to appear in the screen ,instead of infinity && nan
what could be a solution for this problem

**UPD**:I tried to use `isinf` and `isnan` macros :

```
C3861: 'isinf': identifier not found error 
C3861: 'isnan': identifier not found.
```

(I did include to math.h)
What is the reason for this?

Comment: My program must produce this values and print them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `isinf()` and `isnan()` macros to test wheter a number is an infinite or a NaN.

Comment: I get error C3861: 'isinf': identifier not found
error C3861: 'isnan': identifier not found.(I did include to math.h)

Comment: Aside from multiple argument evaluation issue: `#ifndef isnan #define isnan(x) ((x)!=(x)) #endif`

Comment: I think these macros/functions/whatever are C99. Though you may be able to define them yourself, a little comment about the C99ness of these may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your program.cpp

```
#ifndef isinf
#define isinf(x) ((x)!=(x))
#endif


#ifndef isnan 
#define isnan(x) ((x)!=(x)) 
#endif
```

Comment: How would you distinguish NAN from INF in this case?

Answer (score 1):

That's just how the standard library of your compiler treats those special values. If you want different treatment you need to write your own print function that detects the special values and prints the text that you desire.

Comment: Should be called "the nonstandard library"... ;-)